# Convertir número binario a decimal

Tags: c#

Tengo el codigo para convertir de Un numero entero a Binario, Pero no he podido hacer para que me convierta ese número Binario a un decimal: Aquí les dejo el código que use para convertirlo a Binario.

```
int poc = 128;
string bin = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    if (r >= poc)
    {
        bin += "1";
        r = r - poc;
    }
    else 
    {
        bin += "0";
    }
    poc = poc / 2;
}
MessageBox.Show(bin);
```

Comment: ¿Es necesario hacerlo manualmente o es también posible usar las funciones disponibles en el framework de .net?

Comment: Manualmente@james_bond

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para convertir de binario a decimal, debes tomar la posición de cada digito (leyendolo desde derecha a izquierda) y elevandolo al cuadrado, lo que resulte lo sumas a la cuenta actual (siempre y cuando el digito sea 1, 0 no cuenta), por ejemplo:

```
static int BinarioADecimal(string input)
{
    char[] array = input.ToCharArray();
    // Invertido pues los valores van incrementandose de derecha a izquierda: 16-8-4-2-1
    Array.Reverse(array);
    int sum = 0; 

    for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == '1')
        {
            // Usamos la potencia de 2, según la posición
            sum += (int)Math.Pow(2, i);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, Me sirvió de mucho tu respuesta (y)