# ¿Cómo multiplicar números binarios?

Tags: c

Inicialmente intenté convertir los números ingresados a decimal para poder hacer la multiplicación y nuevamente convertir el resultado a binario pero creo que falla en algunos casos aunque no se en cuáles, ¿alguien conoce una mejor manera de resolver el problema?

**Entrada**

Dos números en binario

**Salida**

El resultado de la multiplicación de los dos números en binario

Les dejo mi intento.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int Bi_a_Decimal(char n[]);
void Binario(int n, int bin[], int &cont);
int main()
{
    char a[100], b[100];
    int bin[1000], cont = 0;
    int n, i;
    printf("Ingresa el primer numero en binario: ");
    scanf("%s", a);
    printf("Ingresa el segundo numero en binario : ");
    scanf("%s", b);
    n = Bi_a_Decimal(a);
    i = Bi_a_Decimal(b);
    Binario((n * i), bin, cont);
    printf("\nEl resultado de la multiplicacion es:\n");
    for (int i = cont - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d", bin[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
int Bi_a_Decimal(char n[])
{
    int resultado = 0, i = 0;
    for (i = strlen(n) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (n[i] == '1')
        {
            resultado += 1 * pow(2, strlen(n) - 1 - i);
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
void Binario(int n, int bin[], int &cont)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        while (n > 0)
        {
            bin[cont] = n % 2;
            n /= 2;
            cont++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        bin[cont] = 0;
        cont++;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141049/convertir-n%c3%bamero-binario-a-decimal entra aqui

Comment: La multiplicación binaria tiene las mismas reglas que la multiplicación decimal (solo están en distinta base), por qué no multiplicas los números binarios directamente? Así te ahorras las conversiones!

Comment: De hecho creo que ese es el objetivo del ejercicio, darte cuenta de que las reglas matemáticas aplican igual ya sea en binario, hexal, octal, decimal, hexadecimal, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C se pueden leer los números en diferentes bases, es decir, las puedes leer como decimales, binarios, octales, hexadecimales, etc. Con ayuda de `strto...` lo podemos lograr muy fácilmente. Aunque claro, sólo se pueden leer números enteros, puesto que los flotantes tienen un formato muy distinto.

- Para leer enteros con signo existen: [strtol y strtoll](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)
- Para leer enteros sin signo existen: [strtoul y strtoull](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul)

Este ejemplo lo trataré con enteros sin signo, además voy a usar ***`size_t`***  sinónimo de `unsigned long long`

Para convertir un *char array* a binario es muy simple, sólo basta con pasarle un 2 a la función.

## Conversión de *char array* a número binario

```
strtoull("  01110100101fgfdgdfg", (char **) trash_ptr, 2);
```

Automáticamente puedes manejar esa entrada como entero y si te das cuenta, mientras la primera parte del *char array* sea correcta (un número binario) puede leer correctamente el número y operar matemáticamente con él.

## Imprimir en consola el número en binario

Para imprimirlo es un poco más difícil. Del código [ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/) tenemos que el carácter '0' es el número **48** y el '1' es el **49**, por este motivo al 1 o 0 de los bits del número le sumaremos 48.

Para saber si es 0 o 1 el bit hacemos las [operaciones bitwise](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/) (operaciones que trabajan a nivel bit)

Para ello usaremos las siguientes operaciones:

1. `>>` desplazamiento a la derecha
2. `&` operación ***AND*** a nivel de bits

El desplazamiento a la derecha de n bits es lo mismo que dividir el número entre `2 ^ n` (se trunca el resultado, es decir que: 65 / 2 = 32).

La operación *AND* 1 nos permite saber si es par o impar, con ello determinamos si es 0 o 1 el número que debemos poner y la operación completa queda como:

```
48 + ((number >> i) & 1)

// O sea que quedaría finalmente como

for (int i = 0; i < numero_de_bits_del_número; ++i) {
    // Este sería el 0 o 1 de nuestro número binario
    48 + ((number >> i) & 1);
}
```

Donde i es una variable que va de 0 al número de bits

## Código completo

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool readSizeTNumber(size_t * number, unsigned short radix);
void printBin(size_t number);

/**
 * @param argc Number of arguments passed on command execution
 * @param argv Array of string arguments
 * @return program exit status
 */
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    size_t number_1, number_2;
    errno = 0;

    printf("\nEnter the first number:\t");

    if (!readSizeTNumber(&number_1, 2)) {
        perror("Invalid number. Expected a binary number");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("\nEnter the second number:\t");

    if (!readSizeTNumber(&number_2, 2)) {
        perror("Invalid number. Expected a binary number");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printBin(number_1 * number_2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * prints a unsigned long long number in binary representation
 * @param number
 */
void printBin(size_t number) {
    /* however many bits are in an integer */
    int size = CHAR_BIT * sizeof number;
    char output[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        output[size -1 - i] = 48 + ((number >> i) & 1);
    }
    output[size] = '\0';

    printf("\r%s", output);
}

/**
 * This function serves for advancing your buffer pointer in stdin until the last position
 */
void cleanInputBuffer() {

    errno_t errno_temp = errno;
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    errno = errno_temp;

}

/**
 * This function reads a number from stdin as string and
 * tries to convert it to a unsigned long long int value
 * @param number The pointer to the variable where the result will be written
 * @param radix The input number radix must be between 2 and 36 inclusive
 * @return true if operation was successful, false in other case
 */
bool readSizeTNumber(size_t * number, unsigned short radix) {
    errno = 0;
    char temp[64];
    const char * ptr;
    fgets(temp, 64, stdin);
    cleanInputBuffer();

    *number = strtoull(temp, (char **) &ptr, radix);
    if (ptr == temp)
        return false;

    return errno == 0;
}
```

**Anotaciones**

- Se usan [errnos](https://linux.die.net/man/3/errno), pues son útiles en el [manejo de errores](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_error_handling.htm)
- Se limpia ***STDIN*** cada que se lee del *stream*

Comment: me Marca el siguiente error cuando intento compilar <stdin>:65:3: error: unknown type name 'errno_t'
                errno_t errno_temp = errno;

Comment: Probablemente sea la versión... creo que sólo funciona con C11, pero puedes cambiar el errno_t por un int, es lo mismo